# Program that prints out the initials of a given name

Tags: beginner, c, strings, programming-challenge

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    // store user input
    char * name = get_string();

    // print out the first character of firts string
        printf("%c", toupper(name[0]));

    // iterate through name
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(name); i < n; i++)
    {
        // if i'th character is a space print next character as uppercase
        if (name[i - 1] == ' ')
        {
            printf("%c", toupper(name[i]));

        }

    }
    // print new line following initials
    printf("\n");

}
```

It does what it's supposed to do but I'm concerned about the style of the program.

Comment: I've changed your title  because, The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for examples

Answer (score 2):

Your code is buggy. It might seem to work, but accessing `name[-1]` invokes undefined behavior. You do that in the first iteration of the `for` loop. To fix it, start at `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`.

The next instance of undefined behavior is when you call `toupper(name[i])`. The functions from `<ctype.h>` must not be called with a `char` as their argument. It must always be an `unsigned char` or the value of the macro `EOF`. To fix this, call `toupper((unsigned char) name[i])`.

The proper type for array indexes is not `int`, but `size_t`. Therefore the loop should start with `for (size_t i = 1, n = strlen(name)`.

You have a typo: `firts` instead of `first`.

Other than that, the code looks good. In some months you will be able to remove all the comments because they are obvious to you. But until then, they should stay.

To make your program even more correct, you could change the condition `name[i - 1] == ' '` to be more precise: `!isalpha((unsigned char) name[i - 1]) && isalpha((unsigned char) name[i])`. Then you won't print an "uppercase space" if the input contains several spaces in a row.

Answer (score 1):

C strings are simply an array of bytes that is terminated by a NUL byte.  How, then, does `strlen()` work?  It contains a loop to walks along the array until it finds the NUL terminator.

But your code also tests every character of the array until it reaches the end.  It would therefore be simpler and more efficient for you to stop when you encounter the `'\0'` terminator, instead of incrementing a counter.

---

To print a single character, it would be simpler to use the `putchar(…)` function rather than `printf("%c", …)` or `printf("\n")`.